# Vim plugin for Opening most recently edited files

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm trying to find a vim plugin that restores the most recently edited files in a directory. It's similar to [this plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=521), but this is the functionality that I'm trying to define.

Suppose I have a directory X with these three files:

```
hello.cpp, main.cpp, Makefile
```

Say I'd open them up in vim, split windows accordingly, etc.

Then I type `:wqa` within vim (write, quit all), do some stuff outside vim, and decide to edit files again.

The functionality I want is, if I type `vim` in the command line within directory X, the windows should open up *with the same split settings as before*. I also shouldn't have to specify which files I want to open.

Has anyone heard of such a plugin / is there a quick vimscript for this?

Comment: Other possibilities: a) don't quit Vim, b) use a terminal multiplexer like screen or tmux to persist your session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify) plugin provides exactly what I'm looking for. The session handling is exactly what I want.

(Someone posted the link to startify here, but it seems like he deleted his comment.)

Answer (score 1):

i use the `vim-session` plugin. it is very easy to use and you can save multiple sessions and restore them.

here is the link: https://github.com/xolox/vim-session

i have this in my `.vimrc`

```
" i want to autosave the last session as 'default' 
let g:session_autosave = 'yes' 
" but i dont want to restore the last session automaticaly 
let g:session_autoload = 'no' 
" every instance of vim should overwrite the default session when closed. 
let g:session_default_overwrite = 1 
" i dont need my colorsettings saved to the session. 
let g:session_persist_colors = 0
```

when i want to save a session i simply type `:SaveSession <NAME>` and when i want to restore a session i type `:OpenSession <NAME>`.

if you want to automaticaly restore the default session (the one that is saved automaticaly when vim is closed) use this in your `.vimrc`

```
let g:session_autoload = 'yes'
```

**info:**

- `vim-session` depends on https://github.com/xolox/vim-misc
- the sessions are saved under `~/.vim/sessions/` (maybe you have to create
  this folder if the plugin didn't do that for you)

have fun!

Comment: I think I'm going to stick to my original solution, just because it seems that both are a solution to the problem, but Startify seems more heavily developed. Thanks anyways!

Comment: thats absolutely a good decision, i have just documented it for anybody who is searching for a solution, (so he could choose between the two).